# How to Generate JSON object with a header?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5

Im new at this Objective-c programming. My issue is that i need to create a header with the name "X-FBR-App" and the content of this header is a JSON String. The JSON strings content is 5 parameters. The parameters looks like this:

```
NSString *nid = @":";
    NSString *vocab = @":";
    NSString *inturl = @"testoverview";
    NSString *mail = @"your@fbr.dk";
    NSString *md5pw = @"password";
```

Im using iOS5 and the built in JSON lib. Any ideas of how to do this ?

Comment: Yes, the "X-FBR-App" is a http header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this...

```
NSString *nid = @":";
    NSString *vocab = @":";
    NSString *inturl = @"testoverview";
    NSString *mail = @"your@fbr.dk";
    NSString *md5pw = @"password";

NSArray *jsonArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:inturl, mail, md5pw, nil]; // create your json array or dict

NSError *error; 

// serialize data
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:jsonArray 
                                                   options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted
                                                     error:&error];

if (! jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Got an error: %@", error);
} else {
    // get json string
    NSString *jsonString = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] autorelease];

    // do a Request

    NSString *url = @"your url";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:30.0];


    [request setValue:jsonString forHTTPHeaderField:@"Field You Want To Set"];

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
}
```

Comment: The last line of code generates a result, is that result the response from the service ?

Comment: No. It starts a asynchronous URL load. Check the docs for that.